# Word (Office) Automation Visual Studio 2013 C++

Tags: c++, ms-word, automation

I have to make a program which can operate with Word documents (edit, view, create) and use C++ with Visual Studio 2013.

I have searched the net and found out VSTO is only available for Visual Basic and C#.

On the Microsoft site there is "How to create an automation project using MFC and a type library" [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/178749) but seems it is written for very old versions of Visual Studio (like 5.0 and 6.0). When I reach the ninth step "Select the Automation tab." it seems there is no such tab in ClassWizzard in my version of Visual Studio.

Is there any way to perform automation with C++ in newer versions of Visual Studio like 2013?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CppAutomateWord-28938be1). Actually I am using the "import" method and it worked for me in console mode(COM method also worked, but it seems to me more complicated), I haven`t tested it for GUI yet. There is not C++ documentation, but can be used Visual Basic API with a bit thinking [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841702%28v=office.14%29.aspx).